# Completeness of $(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_p)$

Tags: analysis, reference-request, functional-analysis

For $p=2$,  $(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_{p})$  is not a complete metric space and its closure is $L^{p}[0,1]$?

I am curious as to whether this is true for all $p<\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, at least for $1\le p<\infty$. The references must be legion; here is one such: Proposition 21.1 on page 258 in Emanuele DiBenedetto: *Real Analysis*. I expect it is also true for $0<p<1$, but those spaces are much harder to study.